# Memory Secure Loading of Database in Android

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, loading

so I have been doing a whole bunch of reading and I realized that the old `AsyncTask` of android requires that we link it to an instance of the activity; however, on orientation change, this destroys this specific activity, and recreates it leading to a memory leak. The first `AsyncTask` refers to the first implementation of the activity while it is the second one that is being displayed.  The `Loader` class of 3.0 and beyond took care of most of this, but I am confused as to how to do database loading when I initialize my app.

Currently I am using AsyncTask, but I realized that if someone does an orientation change during the loading, we get the memory leak.  How can I use the Loader to do this?  I am updating a display (to prevent time out and let the user know what is going on) and when done, I close the alert.

How would I do this load using Loaders?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Jon,

I'm actually not sure what you mean by Asynctask requires an instance of the activity? I use AsyncTasks all the time without ever passing a reference to an activity. Is that something you need to do? Can you get away with using the application context to avoid the activity leak?

Comment: I don't think so since I need to update the progress bar from the async task.

Comment: Jon, I actually wrote a long answer and not sure where it got lost in cyber space. Anyways, what you're planning for is pretty simple to do still without passing an activity context. You can simply use a handler for the activity and send message to it from the onProgressUpdate. Or you can even just send your activity an intent from onProgressUpdate. What's the issue with these 2 solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code to make it clearer. There are plenty of ways to solve your issue. OnProgressUpdate is called on the UI thread so you can simply send a message to the activity via a handler or even an intent to ensure the AsyncTask is only dealing with app context not activity context. Again, post some code please.